# Does R always make a copy of the data when it copies an object?

Tags: r, memory

Consider an array of integers

```
> a <- 1:12
> tracemem(a)
```

Setting the `dim` attribute does not make a copy of the object

```
> dim(a) <- c(3, 2, 2)
> a
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    7   10
[2,]    8   11
[3,]    9   12

> dim(a) <- c(dim(a)[1L], prod(dim(a)[-1L]))
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```

but what if the attribute is set in a function?

```
> f <- function(x) { dim(x) <- c(dim(x)[1L], prod(dim(x)[-1L])); x}
> dim(a) <- c(3, 2, 2)
> f(a)
tracemem[0xb99678 -> 0x1b7aac30]: f 
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```

so now it's made a copy.  I understand `a` and `f(a)` are different objects,
but do these objects point to the same data, or has the data also been
copied?

Comment: I'm almost completely sure that the data gets copied. What indication do you have that it's not copied?

Comment: @Roland I have no indication, but since the data itself hasn't been modified in principle it's possible that it's shared between both objects.

Comment: @Roland Under this setup, if you do `b <- f(a)` you get a tracemem ping. If you then do `b[1,1] <- 42` you get *another* tracemem ping. So, its unclear what's happening. I don't see a reason *why* R would have to copy the entire underlying vector when calling `f` here, whether it is or is not actually doing so.

Comment: @A.Webb I agree with your last sentence. Anyway, this is beyond my knowledge and might be better suited for the r-devel mailing list.

Comment: @A.Webb : not so relevant but `b[1,1] <- 42` subassigns a "double" to an "integer" and, so, "b" would be copied/coerced due to precedence (double > int). Same happens with `b[1, 1] = 42L` though...

Comment: In either case, `b` would have to be copied. The mystery is why we get another tracemem ping when `a` was the only variable we placed the trace on. It would seem to imply that `a` is being subjected to a copy operation at that stage (as well?).

Comment: @A.Webb: You mean if "a" gets, also, copied in `b[, ] <- ..` along with "b"? It seems that "b" just 'inherits' the to-be-traced mark from "a" since `dim<-` (w or w/o copying) keeps "a"'s info in contrast to other functions. E.g. with `a = 1:3; tracemem(a)` compare `(function(x) { dim(x) = c(1, length(x)) })(a)` VS `(function(x) invisible(x + 1L))(a)`.

Comment: @Ernest : Unless I'm missing something, using "a" inside a function increases its `NAM` field which is a condition for copying: `a = 1:3; .Internal(inspect(a)); (function(x) x)(a); .Internal(inspect(a))`. Also, `a = 1:3; tracemem(a); a[[1]] = 2L` VS `a = 1:3; tracemem(a); (function(x) invisible(x))(a); a[[1]] = 2L`

Comment: @alexis_laz I'm not sure how to interpret the output of `inspect`, but using the function `object_size` from `pryr` seems to confirm that indeed it makes a copy of the data

Answer (score 0):

The output of `object_size` from the `pryr` package suggests that the data
is copied.

```
> object_size(list(a))
304 B
> object_size(list(a, a))
312 B
> object_size(list(a, a, a))
328 B
> b <- f(a)
tracemem[0x1fa7660 -> 0xbadae8]: f 
> object_size(list(a, b))
504 B
>
```